# You cannot init this class directly - in your Storyboard/NIB file, set the Class type to one of the subclasses

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using [**SVKit**](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) for displaying a SVG image. This is what I did :

1. Integrated SVG using pod.
2. Took a UIView in my UIViewController (in storyboard).
3. Set its class as SVGKImageView.
4. In viewDidLoad :

   ```
   self.imageView.image = SVGKImage(named: "my-logo")
   ```

In the same line, I get the crash which says :

> Xcode is trying to load this class from a StoryBoard or from a NIB/XIB
>   files. You cannot init this class directly - in your Storyboard/NIB
>   file, set the Class type to one of the subclasses, e.g.
>   SVGKFastImageView'

Comment: What class your @IBOutlet for image view has?

Comment: Well basically you really need to set it to be SVGKFastImageView in your storyboard, and not basic SVGKImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not very obvious but documentation to SVGKImageView states the following:

```
NB: the "SVGKFastImageView" is the one you want 9 times in 10.
The alternative classes (e.g. SVGKLayeredImageView) are for advanced usage.
NB: read the class-comment for each subclass carefully before deciding what to use.
```

Found in source files of **SVKit**